# Incompitable types? int cannot be identidied

Tags: java, types

How can I fix this problem here:

```
Error:(8, 43) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int
```

My code:

```
import jdk.internal.util.xml.Input;

import java.util.*;    
public class HelloWorld { //this is a comment
    public static void main(String[], args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome");
        int grade = input.nextLine();

        if (grade > 60) {
             System.out.println("Admited");
        }
    }
}
```

It says it requires an integer, but it found a string.

Comment: You didn't actually show your code...

Comment: Related: _[What's the difference between JavaScript and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)_

Comment: Scanner.nextLine() returns a String, which cannot be type casted to an int primitive. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Please include all code as formatted text within the question itself, not at images or links to an external code sharing site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

String is an Object, int is a primitive; they are not compatible. Use
    Integer.parseInt(String, 10);
The "radix" will stop certain code analyzers from complaining. Note that a String that can't be parsed will result in an exception.

Comment: *The "radix" will stop certain code analyzers from complaining.* About what?

Comment: Apparently, some code analyzers think that using the default radix is ambiguous or some such. I was annoyed the first time it happened.